# My MacBook Pro 13" 2020 doesn't boot when I plug in the power adapter and the lid is closed

Tags: startup, big-sur, closed-clamshell

I want to use my MB with external hardware (Display, Keyboard, Mouse) in clamshell mode. Everything is set up to work in clamshell mode, display, keyboard and mouse are connected. I basically shut down my MB after using it in clamshell mode.
When my MB is open and I plug the power adapter in, it starts the booting process, as expected.
However, when the lid is closed and the power adapter is plugged in, it only makes the charging confirmation sound, but it doesn't boot.
I'd like to boot my MB into clamshell mode.
Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Usually it will need an external display plugged in and ready - at least it works with mine...

Comment: @SolarMike I actually have that too

Comment: That is not what you state in your question, if you don’t explain exactly what you are doing then we can’t help.

Comment: @SolarMike I thought saying "I want to use it in clamshell mode (external display, mouse and keyboard)" was enough, but I updated it to be more explicit now.

Comment: The ability to power on a MacBook Pro seems to be different between the former Intel versions and the newer Apple Silicon based Macbook Pros.  My former Intel based MacBook Pro had no problem booting with the lid closed when a thunderbolt with power delivery was connected to it, but I can't get my newer MacBook Pro (M2 Max, 2023) to power on in clamshell mode when I connect my dock to it. The dock has a monitor connected to it, just like my former computer's dock had.